# android RadioButton option on the right side of the text

Tags: android, radio-button

How can I create a `RadioButton` with the option on the right side of the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ok, I use CheckTextView instead

Answer (score 1):

Like [@Arutha mentioned in the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1886822/4230345), you can use a `CheckedTextView`. This can be done by using a built-in Android layout (as I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631839/change-the-side-the-text-appears-on-a-radio-button)) - `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<CheckedTextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd" />
```

If you want to modify it, you can copy-paste the above into a new XML file, and then use the `<include>` tag to include it in your other layouts (under the [Apache 2.0 License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)). You can also use it as a list item, and leave it unchanged.