# Could RadioButton put the Font before button?

Tags: android

I want to realize the function like:

```
Male     ⊙
Female   ⊙
```

How can I handle this using XML or code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the side the text appears on a radio button](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2631839/645270)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:button="@null"   
android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/xxxxx"   
android:paddingLeft="30dip"   
android:text="Male"
```

Answer (score -1):

You could but you will have to create a customized listview for that.

And at the initialization of your listview either in your XML file or in your code, you will have to specify which style should you choose aside from the native style.

Try looking at this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) and also [this](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/), they might help.