# android RadioButton image and text

Tags: android, xml, radio-button

Im using a radio button to create a custom tab host, is working fine, but now I need to show the icon on top and the text underneath the icon,

this is what I have now:
[image: currentState]

but this is what I need:
[image: desiredState]

This is my code:

```
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rad_home"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rad_background"
        android:button="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_background"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rad_text_size" >


    </RadioButton>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rad_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rad_background"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_background"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rad_text_size" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rad_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rad_background"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="VIP"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_background"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rad_text_size" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rad_3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rad_background"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="About"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_background"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rad_text_size" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rad_4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rad_background"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Whats On"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_background"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rad_text_size" />
</RadioGroup>
```

So im setting the button icon with:

> android:button="@null"

for when is empty

and

> android:button="@drawable/home_icon"

for the icon image,
should I use this to set the icon? 
how to organize it as I need it? [icon on top, text bottom]

I tried with a layout inside , but doesnt seem to like it?

how to accomplish this?

thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, it's not easily possible. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631839/change-the-side-the-text-appears-on-a-radio-button). It might help in serving your requirement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this: use drawableTop to show the icon

```
 <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rad_home"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/rad_background"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_icon"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Home"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_background"
    android:textSize="@dimen/rad_text_size" >
```

Comment: `@null` make my day..  useful for me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use textview :-

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/rad_home"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="home" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear i can suggest you that try to Combine button text instead simple button.In Your code you try

```
 android:background="@drawable/rad_background"
        android:button=**"@null"**
```

Instead use my code and display combine button like this.

```
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCrop"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_crop_selector"
                    android:text="@string/btnCrop"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextButton"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

This will be help to you.