# Is it possible in android to put the drawableLeft image of radio button to the extreme left of the icon?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-drawable, radio-group

By following this link [android-radiobutton-image-and-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514728/android-radiobutton-image-and-text)  I'm able to show radio button with image and text both.

if I use drawableLeft, the drawable image comes in between the radio icon(circular icon to show if selected or not) and the text.

But what I want is to show first the drawable image to extreme left, then radio icon having some space(margin/padding) from drawable and then the text to right side.

I'm able to show below, but i want that tractor image to the left of that circular icon
[image]

my code below:`

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group_machine_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_btn_tractor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/tractor_icon"

                android:text="@string/tractor_label" />

            <View
                style="@style/Divider"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/black_tint_40" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_btn_combine"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/car_icon"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="@string/combine_label" />
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>`
```

I tried using taking a ImageView to left of RadioButton, then the issue comes that click on ImageView don't select the radio button.

So is it possible?

Comment: android:drawableLeft have you tried out this

Comment: I think you have to try Custom radio button for whatever you want to this radiobutton.....See this Github example https://github.com/ceryle/RadioRealButton

Comment: @ERVishalSenjaliya thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution::

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group_machine_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/tractor_icon"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_btn_tractor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/tractor_label" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                style="@style/Divider"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/black_tint_40" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/car_icon"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_btn_combine"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:text="@string/combine_label" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: I have tried this, but the click on ImageView don't select the radio button, so that part of row looks unresponsive. Is it possible to pass the click event of imageview to selected event event of radiobutton?

Comment: then write code for on clicklistener and set selection to that radio.

Comment: @ShirishHerwade add click listener to lineralayout that is given for each radiobutton, take the state of radio button and toggle it.

Comment: @RahulAhuja yes I also think that I have to go to that work-around, if I don't want to create custom(extended) radionButton :)...... thanks  both(Nitin Patel also) of you

Comment: For this you have use If..Else statement.Suppose If user click on that ImageView then particular radiobutton ID is checked.And use sharedPreference to get the state of radiobutton

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.so.gradledemo.MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="camera" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true" 
                android:text="frame" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="arrow"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

adjust height and width according to your requirement