# How can I align radio buttons to the right of associated text?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following radio buttons inside a radio group of similar buttons. By default a button is on the left of the associated text. How do I get the button itself to be on the right of the associated text?

```
<RadioGroup
  android:id="@+id/points_radio_group"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/do_tastk_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:onClick="doTask1"
    android:paddingLeft="40dip"
    android:text="@string/task_name_1"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

  <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/do_tastk_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:onClick="doTask2"
    android:paddingLeft="40dip"
    android:text="@string/task_name_2"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: I've used a trick to achieve this in all SDKs with default UI and default select behavior, in below answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42734740/4832356

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use

```
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
```

So your code will be like:

```
<RadioGroup
  android:id="@+id/points_radio_group"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/do_tastk_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:onClick="doTask1"
    android:paddingLeft="40dip"
    android:text="@string/task_name_1"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

  <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/do_tastk_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:onClick="doTask2"
    android:paddingLeft="40dip"
    android:text="@string/task_name_2"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: oh, wow. Thanks. For some reason I thought I would need a drawable called `btn_radio`. But I added the lines anyway and it works! +1 too.

Comment: btn_radio is android's own resource for the radio button

Comment: +1 for nice answer..I have created a custom radio button, but your solution is awesome..It is called presence of mind

Comment: @Pragnani thanks.. I was also learned it from someone else :)

Comment: If you do this, then it doesn't get tinted properly when the parent theme is an `AppCompat` theme.

Comment: when i'm setting android:button="@null" , the radio button is not getting checked(clicked). Im i doing something wrong. please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052820/android-custom-radio-button-not-getting-checked

Comment: hi @ShirishHerwade do you use custm drawable? then u have to set drawable for selected state also.

Comment: @toobsco42 With `AppCompat` you can use this drawable 
`android:drawableRight="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_material"`

Comment: You can use android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"

Comment: Even better with drawableEnd: `android:drawableEnd="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"`

Answer (score 19):

by using

```
android:button="@null"
android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
```

you change radio button format. It is better practice just to align right,

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

on each radioButton, and text will be on left side.

Comment: Just add `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` do the trick keeping appCompat theme

Comment: @alvinmeimoun any idea how to give the radio button icon padding from right if the button with is fill parent?

Answer (score 4):

**You can do in xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right|center" //or "center_vertical" for center text
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:text="hello" />
```

**Following line is enough**

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

Answer (score 3):

easy way add this to your radiobutton in xml

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to add elements dynamically you can try to create a layout with a textview and a radio button with no text on the right.
Something on these lines:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radiobutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/radiobutton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radiobutton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution, as I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631839/change-the-side-the-text-appears-on-a-radio-button) is to use the built in Android layout - `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<CheckedTextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd" />
```

If you want to modify it, you can copy-paste the above into a new XML file, and then use the `<include>` tag to include it in your other layouts (under the [Apache 2.0 License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)). You can also use it as a list item, and leave it unchanged.