# how to put the text on the left of a radio button in android

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I want to put the text of a radio button on the left not on the right

I found this solution

```
        <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radios"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawablePadding="30dp"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:text="first"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Black"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawablePadding="30dp"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:text="second"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/third"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Maroon"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawablePadding="30dp"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:text="third"
            android:textColor="@color/Vanilla"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

but the problem is that the text gravity will be at the left what I want is to put it to right because i'm writing Arabic words

[image]

Comment: Try with  android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_radio"

Comment: For language perspective all you need was one line... that is...(android:layoutDirection="rtl" )..... it is more easier :P

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Add `android:gravity="right"` in each `RadioButton` as follow..

```
  <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radios"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawablePadding="30dp"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:text="first"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="20dip" 
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/Black"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawablePadding="30dp"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:text="second"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="20dp"
         android:gravity="right"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/Maroon"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawablePadding="30dp"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:text="third"
        android:textColor="@color/Vanilla"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="right" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Well, this kindof works... but it gives a different radio button image. On Holo you get another image in the original RadioButton... :(

Comment: but after this, the radio button is not getting checked(clicked). Im i doing something wrong. please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052820/android-custom-radio-button-not-getting-checked

Comment: While the solution works, the first sentence is misleading. The radio buttons are moved to the right of the text, instead of to the left, because of `android:button="@null"` and `android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"`. What `android:gravity="right"` does is aligning the widget to the right of its parent, rather than just the button.

Comment: doesn't work if set programmatically `rb.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);`

Comment: @muhammad-adil if you set `supportRtl=" false "` in manifest you won't get it

Comment: UI came as expected but 'android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"' gives default radiobutton image right side, on selecting RadioButton I can't select,anything wrong

Answer (score 170):

Try adding the following attributes into the `RadioButton`, it should work, this way you still get to keep the ripple effect on the radio button:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:textAlignment="textStart"
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

Remember to set `supportsRtl` property to true in your application manifest.

for eg:

```
   <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:text="The test item a"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

         ....                       

    </RadioGroup>
```

would give out:

[image]

Comment: this method need minimum sdk level 17 how can I make view like that if I have the minimum sdk level < 17

Comment: you should use appcompat radiobutton to bypass sdk level limitation

Comment: Im not sure if this used to work, it seems like it, but for me it does not produce the result in the screenshot - not even close

Comment: Seems like `android:textAlignment` is not needed.

Answer (score 49):

Based on the answer of [Irshu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155282/irshu) I suggest the following solution which uses the material ripple effect and produces the following outcome:

[image: Demo]

If you want the dividers as shown in the GIF than simply add a view with the height of 1 and a background color between the radiobuttons.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/radioButton1">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But android:layoutDirection="rtl" is not  necessary.

Answer (score 22):

There is property called `android:drawableRight` which will set your drawable right side of your text  and set `android:button` as `null`. check below piece of code:

*Note: This is sample, you can apply to your all radioButton.*

```
 <RadioButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@null"
             android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
             android:text="Left"/>
```

Comment: but after this, the radio button is not getting checked(clicked). Im i doing something wrong. please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052820/android-custom-radio-button-not-getting-checked

Answer (score 13):

Just add:

```
android:button="@null"
android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
```

Answer (score 13):

add this in xml : ( 4.2 and above)

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

for older version than 4.2 use ViewCompat from android.support.v4.view:

```
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(findViewById(R.id.radio_button), ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Answer (score 9):

Try adding the following attributes into the RadioButtons, it work

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup_sample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_sample_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:text="دریافت کد با ایمیل"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_sample_tow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:text="دریافت کد با پیامک"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

this picture of my sample code

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/myRb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
/>
```

Now Rtl will Move your text to right,

Answer (score 5):

Very simple, you want the text to appear in the left of the radio button, you just have to change the layout direction to rtl (== right to left):

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is still wondering how to achieve this, here's a better solution in my opinion:
[RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) class extends [LineareLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html). You can add a simple radio button and a TextView beside it and easily have the same effect:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="خانم"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="آقا"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/male"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RadioGroup>
```

Which then makes a layout like below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Don't get confused to see lines of codes,Its just a simple line

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl";//right to left,if you want you can set ltr
```

put this like

```
        <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:text="English"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        />
```

and careful to refresh your preview better to select Design not blue print

Answer (score 4):

you can change direction for your `RadioButtons` in `RadioGroup`
add `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` in your RadioGroup attribute.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/role_radioGroup_ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/manager" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/fleetVehicle" />

   <RadioButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/personalVehicle" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code :

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="right">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="اول"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

result :
[show result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mVR1.png)

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 3):

to keep material style use android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"

```
<RadioButton
   android:id="@+id/radioButton"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:button="@null"
   android:text="rtl button"
   android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"/>
```

Comment: This one is interesting because it doesn't use android:layoutDirection="rtl". Unfortunately, rtl is going to cause the check to switch sides when the interface legit needs to reverse.

Answer (score 2):

I've used a trick like the code below to achieve this in all SDKs with default UI and default select behavior:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="RadioButton 1"
            android:textColor="@color/Black" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:scaleX="-1" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="RadioButton 2"
            android:textColor="@color/Black" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:scaleX="-1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now for make the buttons single selectable, just write the code for buttons `onCheckedChanged` listener and make other buttons unchecked.

Like this:

```
rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
        if(checked)
            rb2.setChecked(false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ["CustomChoiceList" example](http://developer.android.com/samples/CustomChoiceList/index.html), there it is explained how you can create either your own check boxes/radio buttons or how you can create a ListView with the default check boxes/radio buttons used in the android settings, for example. You should especially note the res/layout/sample_main.xml file, it expains much.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code or explanation as part of your answer rather than linking to another resource.

Answer (score 1):

```
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fontPath="@string/font_nunito_light"
            android:text="Male"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/selector_radio"
            android:button="@null"
            android:id="@+id/rb_"
            android:checked="true"
           android:textSize="@dimen/sp_15"
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question you still might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users.

Answer (score 0):

try this code and change the values to your arabic words..

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioMale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_male"
                android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_female" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDisplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_display" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: oh man, what is this code it's the default radio button. what I want is to have the radio button like the picture above
radio button on the right of the text and the text should be aligned to the right

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has mentioned this, below is the way you can do it Programmatically if someone is trying to do it

```
RadioButton button = new RadioButton(context);
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(button, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

// Create the layout params for our buttons
RadioGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new 
RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
button.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following attributes on the RadioButton, only layoutDirection won't work if you are updating the RadioButton text dynamically -

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:textAlignment="textStart"
android:textDirection="ltr"
```

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue on kotlin with programmatically case, here is my solved code :

```
 val radioButton = RadioButton(requireActivity())
            radioButton.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL
            radioButton.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START

            // Set layout gravity to start
            radioButton.layoutParams = RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            ).apply {
                gravity = Gravity.START
            }
radioGroup.addView(radioButton)
```