# Android how to make option selection with radio button

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to make options select design with two radio buttons selections. Like image below. Please help to do this.

[image]

Comment: can you explain a bit more

Comment: @Kailash Dabhi, it means that label text on the left and radio button icon on the right side.

Comment: Try to use for "Option1" TextView component, and create RadioButton with no label.

Comment: Use two text view and in front of that text view use radio button with no text

Comment: @offmind is right go with that

Comment: The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914792/how-to-put-the-text-on-the-left-of-a-radio-button-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(new CharSequence[] {"Item1", "Item2"}, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
```

Here you can create a dialog with radio button and text