# Android RadioButton Direction

Tags: android, radio-button, material-design

How can I change Radiobutton's direction to rtl in my app ?

(Button align right and the text align left)

I don't want radiobutton lose it's material design.

Comment: post you code what you have done :)

Comment: I've used a trick to achieve this in all SDKs with default UI and default select behavior, in below answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42734740/4832356

Answer (score 3):

**use android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle" .**

```
 <RadioButton
       android:id="@+id/radioButton"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:button="@null"
       android:text="rtl button"
       android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="item"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>
```