# How to put text on the left of radio button?

Tags: android, radio-button, text-alignment

I wanna put the text of radio button on the left of its button. if I use these codes in each radio button the default button theme is lost!

```
android:button="@null"
android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
```

I mean btn_radio has its theme, I wanna use another theme.

moreover this code `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` 
is not worked for me!

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914792/how-to-put-the-text-on-the-left-of-a-radio-button-in-android

Comment: if I use those codes in each radio button the default button theme is lost!

Comment: I mean btn_radio has its theme, I wanna use another theme.