# Android: radiobutton text not well aligned with number

Tags: android, radio-button, alignment, text-alignment

I have an unbelievable problem. I have 1 radiogroup with 2 radiobuttons, I'd like each radiobutton width is match_parent with text align on left. But I don't know why, the first one is aligned right as you can see on the picture[image]

Here's the code

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgPasswordSendMode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle|end"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">
     <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/phoneRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:text="******6043" />
     <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/emailRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:text="test@test.com" />
</RadioGroup>
```

When I change ******6043 by only ****** or other text, the label is well aligned on the left.
Based on [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914792/how-to-put-the-text-on-the-left-of-a-radio-button-in-android/54646959), I added

```
android:button="@null"
android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

but nothing changed.

Why it's like that and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you use `match_content`  for width and `wrap_content` for height

Comment: that does not change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you should add the `android:textDirection="ltr"` which defines the direction of the text from Left to Right. The `android:layoutDirection="rtl"`
defines the direction of layout drawing so it will draw the radio button to the right side of text.

Your layout should be like the below:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgPasswordSendMode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle|end"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/phoneRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textDirection="ltr"
        android:text="******6043" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/emailRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textDirection="ltr"
        android:text="test@test.com" />
</RadioGroup>
```

**Result:**

[image: radio_button]

Comment: Thank you so much. I spend so much time to find the solution. If I could, I'll kiss you :). Do you know why without ` android:textDirection="ltr"`  it worked with text but not with number?

Comment: I think this it seems to be a bug in the RadioButton it should work for both letters and numbers after you have set the width to be match_parent and  android:textAlignment="textStart"