# android set radio button right from text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiobutton

good morning !

i would like to set an radio button right from the his text.
i saw here an solution like this way:

```
 <RadioButton
            android:drawablePadding="30dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:button="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:paddingStart="18dp"
            android:paddingEnd="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/DefaultGrey"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:checked="false" />
```

this set the radio button right from his text, but i dislike the style of the alternative radio button, which i get with this code.

is there an way to use the default radio button style?

Comment: Is this for a `right-to-left` layout?

Comment: #Ghost108 Inform please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to put the text on the left of a radio button in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914792/how-to-put-the-text-on-the-left-of-a-radio-button-in-android)

Comment: android:text="Left" set only the text to "Left" not the position

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Do you need to change your radio button style ? If yes then customize it. You will get sure default style because you'r using default `@android:drawable/btn_radio` icon.

Comment: i only would like to set the text left form the radio button. this type of radio button, which i can drag and drop into my activity in the designer

Comment: you are using RadioGroup then put android:layout_gravity="right" and each RadioButton to set android:layout_gravity="right"

Comment: done. but the text ist not left from the radio button.

Comment: RadioButton to set android:gravity="right"

Comment: check this demo i think help you http://www.programering.com/a/MjNwkDMwATM.html

Comment: refere this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133089/how-can-i-align-radio-buttons-to-the-right-of-associated-text) hope it will help you

Comment: works ! thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved but next Problem**

This was the solution:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgRight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/HeaderSectionSort"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_selected_sort"
        android:text="@string/Radio1"
        android:textColor="@color/DefaultGrey"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#f4f4f4"
        android:id="@+id/Seperator3"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_selected_sort"
        android:buttonTint="@color/DefaultGreen"
        android:text="@string/Radio2"
        android:textColor="@color/DefaultGrey"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#f4f4f4"
        android:id="@+id/Seperator4"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_selected_sort"
        android:text="Radio3"
        android:textColor="@color/DefaultGrey"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />


</RadioGroup>
```

Result:

[image]

Problem:
i would like to hide the drawable (ic_selected_sort) at the beginning programmatically. and on click set it to visible.

i try something like this:

```
        rb1.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.white);
```

but i doesn't take effect.
any ideas? :)

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin programmatic solution:

```
private fun createDrawableRightRadioButton(message: String): RadioButton {

    val radioButton = RadioButton(context)
    radioButton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)

    radioButton.setText(message)
    radioButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.text_medium)); //<dimen name="text_medium">14sp</dimen>
    radioButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.radio_grey_text_selector))
    radioButton.typeface = Typeface.create("roboto", Typeface.NORMAL)

    radioButton.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL
    radioButton.setButtonDrawable(0) // for removing default drawable
    radioButton.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10)
    radioButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.gostyle_radio_button_selector, 0); // for adding drawable on the right
    radioButton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL

    return radioButton

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**You just need to add the following code in Radio Button**

```
   android:layoutDirection="rtl"

   eg.
   <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/rb_male"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layoutDirection="rtl"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="@color/text_color"
         android:text="Male" />
```

Comment: Short and simple solution with RTL direction, nice!

Comment: Great answer. This works with LinearLayout as well!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/radiobutton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/radiobutton"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radiobutton"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
```

Comment: there is the problem, that i can only touch the radio button to select it, not the text

Comment: you can add one layout and put both controller inside that layout (RadioButton,textview) and set click of that layout and handle Radio button select and unselect

Comment: you are use the <RadioGroup> ?

Comment: you are using RadioGroup then put android:layout_gravity="right" and each RadioButton to set android:gravity="right"

Comment: if we do this way, then we have to handle the clicks of textview also with more handling if we want to choose one. Using RadioGroup, we wont need to handle click events for the textview separately.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've added to the Checkbox in my project:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_checked="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/tick_green" >
    <shape >
        <size android:width="@dimen/d32"
            android:height="@dimen/d32"/>
    </shape>
</item>

 <item android:state_checked="false"
 android:drawable="@drawable/uncheck" >
    <shape >
        <size android:width="@dimen/d32"
            android:height="@dimen/d32"/>
    </shape>
    </item>
```

And my checkbox code looks like this:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/reason_cb_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/my_checkbox_drawable"  <- set it here
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/d16"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/d16"
    android:text="@string/some_text" />
```

You can probably create a similar drawable and set it to your RadioButton drawableRight attribute.

Note: "uncheck" is a transparent drawable that I created  for the unchecked state.